# Is it possible to use rrule(freq, count, byeaster) with an orthodox method of easter?

Tags: python, rrule

Is it possible to change the method of `byeaster` in

```py
dateutil.rrule.rrule(freq, count, byeaster)
```

somehow?
I need to use the orthodox one, which is like

```
dateutil.easter.easter(year, method=2)
```

instead of default

```
dateutil.easter.easter(year, method=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it ended with a feature request on GitHub, as it seems not to be possible in current version (dateutils-2.8.0).

rrule simply invokes `easter(year)` where needed without any chance to select an algorithm.